# How can I use fly mode on a camera with constraint?

Tags: animation, camera, constraints

[image]

as you can see if I try to use fly mode on a constrained camera it wouldn't let me
not even if i check "offset" in the copy location constraint

Comment: i would say: obviously you can't...

Comment: @Chris I think I remember doing this in 2.7X version?

Comment: Maybe it was possible in older version. But the error is pretty obvious….